# Can you set an image to the $_FILES superglobal without having a user submit it with an html input tag?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make a website and I am using Indigo eclipse.  When I run my website the images are shown in the browser inside the editor, but when I am running it in any other real browser the images are not shown.  I do not know why that is happening, but I do remember making another website in Indigo eclipse where users could upload photos and every web browser displayed those pictures so I want to try and use that same code again but in that website the users were uploading images through the html input tag the file was automatically put in the $_FILES superglobal after they click submit. In the website that I am making now, I do not want a user inputing a file so is there any other way to get an inside the $_FILES super global without using an input tag?

Comment: They are probably not showing because the path is wrong.

Comment: The fact you're using Eclipse is completely irrelevant. Check image paths.

Comment: I checked again and the paths are correct that was also the first thing I checked and then I did it once more before I submitted the quuestion I checked it again and they are correct is there any other possible fix?

Comment: @DavidBélanger Is coorect. If the images do not show whne placed in a simple <img> tag then the path must be wrong. There is no other reason for them not to show.

Comment: you may want to include the image path you're using, as well as your folder structure

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser's console?